# Update record on unique constraint on batch store jooq

Tags: java, postgresql, jooq

I am trying to insert the records using batchStore using jooq. I need to know how we can update the record on unique constraint, currently it is throwing
an exception that the record already exists

```
SQL Error [23505]: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint
```

Below is the code

```
DSLContext create = getDSLContext();
List<UserRecord> userRecordList = new ArrayList<>();
for (Users user : model.getUsers()) {
    User record = create.newRecord(user);
    userRecordList.add(record);
}
create.batchStore(userRecordList).execute();
```

Currently it is inserting the records fine, but when duplicate record found on the basis of unique constraint it should update the record

Comment: Indeed, the `batchStore()` command does not execute a SQL `MERGE` statement semantics, but shortcuts calling `UpdatableRecord.store()` on each individual record, running the `store()` commands in batch. There's a feature request to improve the docs: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/6584

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved this issue by using a common interface UpdatableRecord, first I have used a fetchOne() query to get the record on the basis of the unique constraint which will give the UpdatableRecord and then set the values with the updated ones which are then added to userRecordlist which will be further passed into batchStore

Answer (score 0):

I had to do the same as JN_newbie. For completeness here's what my solution looked like.

```
// OpeningtimeRecord is the JOOG generated record for the Openingtime table.
List<OpeningtimeRecord> openingRecords = new ArrayList<>();

// Openingtime is the POJO generated from the database schema for the table.
for (Openingtime opening : openings)
{
    // Check to see if this record already exists in the database
    OpeningtimeRecord record = dbContext.fetchOne(*TABLE*, *TABLE.ID*.eq(opening.getId()));

    // If it doesn't exist then we need to create a new record
    if (null == record)
    {
        record = dbContext.newRecord(*TABLE*, opening);
    }
    else
    {
        // Update the record with any new data from the POJO.
        record.from(opening);
    }

    openingRecords.add(record);
}

int[] results = this.dbContext.batchStore(openingRecords).execute();
```